# Fancybox modal scrolling does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, fancybox

trying to figure out something. The fancybox modals here (http://gloriasdj.se/schedule/) doesn't work. Sometimes scrollbars show, but you can only click and drag (not mousewheel or trackpad) but most of the time it doesn't.

I tried overriding the fancybox js and css (judging from what i can understand, not really a developer) but to no avail I failed.

Currently, I have this in my CSS:

```
.fancybox-inner .event-area .event .col-md-12 {
   height:400px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that's the correct selector, or I might be wrong. Someone please shed some light on me. Been figuring this out for days!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Current code is not useful please remove that

`.fancybox-inner .event-area .event .col-md-12 {
   height:400px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}`

Just add few css in your style.css file

`.event-area > .row > .col-md-12 {
    height: 363px;
}`